# Is there any blockchain-based mail services available?

Tags: blockchain, email

According to technology behind the Bitcoin, I'd be interested in using decentralized blockchain-email. Cryptamail was only one I found but they've been told that it is in beta right now but last update seems to be in year 2014. The site isn't working.

Is Cryptamail really something, what we have to wait before start using decentralized email at tor-network or upperground?

Comment: What do you mean by blockchain-based mail? That your emails are stored on the blockchain?